# How to compress native client .nexe binary file

Tags: google-nativeclient

Is there any command like `pnacl-compress` to compress an already compiled native client `.nexe` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pnacl-bccompress` compresses a `.pexe` file. `.nexe` files are either x86-32, x86-64, ARM or MIPS, and compressing these is trickier and probably not the best approach.

Instead I suggest playing with LLVM's command-line options to generate smaller bitcode files, which will result in smaller `.nexe` files. First, run `pnacl-clang` with `--pnacl-driver-verbose` to see the command lines being run. Then add or remove options from `opt` (note that the order of these is important!). Especially useful will be the inlining threshold, and `mergefuncs`. You can disassemble the intermediate bitcode files with `llvm-dis` to see if there's anything unexpected in there, or if LLVM generates extra big functions or globals. LLVM has a bunch of other command line options to play with, but those aren't [P]NaCl specific at all so I'll avoid listing them here.